# How can I attach my drain arm to an existing p trap

Tags: plumbing, sink

The previous sink was directly above the p trap, the new sink is now off centered. Attaching a direct connect waste arm puts me about 3/4" below the 90 deg elbow.

[image: Waste Arm]

A solution is that I try to move the existing cutout to align the p trap with the new hole, and then use a longer wall bend.

I was looking for a 90 deg elbow that had a straight section in one direction instead of 2 threaded ends but had no luck finding that. As I type this I suppose that would just be a waste arm with a threaded end. Would that be functional solution?

Answer (score 3):

Change the drain basket to a shallower one.  The one you have there looks unusually deep.  I think that will be the easiest way to get back the height you need.

**OR**

Don't add a horizontal run before the trap.  The two extra 90 degree bends are costing you in height.   Just replace the existing trap arm, which has been cut so short that it looks like a plain 90 degree bend, with a new one that is long enough to reach your new sink and then use a plain straight tailpiece on the sink.  You will have to cut out more of the cabinet shelf to accommodate this.  Hopefully it won't weaken the shelf too much.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you're going to want to lower the trap by 19mm or so so that it can be disassembled.  After you figure out how to do that (eg: replace the outlet pipe with a taller one) the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Unless i am missing something, you turn both pipes at 45 deg to face each other, no extra bend required.

Comment: the problem is the hight

Comment: the parts also seem to be assembled in an unusual arrangement,  the the sharp 90 bend usually the dam,.